# How get original domain by origin using express and node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform

I am building a web application, and want to add limit by getting request origin domain name, so i can verify is it my domain or anybody else going to use my data.
to achieve this

```
var app = express();

app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
    var reqHeaders = req.headers;
    if( reqHeaders.origin === 'http://hotmail.com' ){
        next();
    }
    else{
        console.log('invalid domain: '+reqHeaders.origin);
    }
});
```

and then I created a virtual domain at my windows OS as
(127.0.0.1       hotmail.com) 
and set it by xampp apache, I sent request and amazed by watching it allowed it even you know it is virtual domain not real.

what is solution? how can I check the referrer real identification, domain name etc?

BTW I am using this in parse sever application, if parse server is providing anything for that on application level, then please let me know.
if it is possible in beforesave trigger in cloude code then also please let me know.

thanks.

Comment: You can't reliably detect where custom http requests are coming from.  So, this is probably the wrong way to try to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do.  Usually, this type of issue is addressed by requiring login credentials and then looking for abuse of service on a particular login credential and then banning that credential when abuse detected.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check anything that provided in headers, at least everything in headers can be changed with custom request.

To prevent request You can use this middleware:

```
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(req.headers.origin !== 'http://hotmail.com' ){
        return next();
    }

    console.log('invalid domain: '+req.headers.origin);
    res.status(400).send();
});
```

but to check You've to use some services that does whois by domain name and check request ip, but this process is very long process and can keep request waiting while it gets response from service.

I do recommend You to use **token** based **authentication/authorization** and to give that tokens to that another parties to provide in request, that will be enough secure and fast.

Checkout my repository: https://github.com/num8er/alttab-nodejs-challenge 
You'll see example of token based auth and filtering.